# Can I simplify this solution?

Tags: java, file, path, simplify

I want to simplify my code.

my code is for listing directories , check if folders contain files : strings.xml and if specific folder contais file , split names of these folders to get language suffix (load it to table or list), example :
my directories tree contains a few folders 
--value 
--value-en
--value-de
--value-pl
--other folders

my code : 
languages is a [] in below example

```html
Path dir_path = Paths.get("D:/Work/Projekty/Java/Tools/Mobilne zasoby/arcadia-drafter/res/");
 DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(dir_path);
 for (Path file_path : stream) 
   {
  DirectoryStream<Path> stream1 = Files.newDirectoryStream(file_path, "strings.xml");
  for (Path xml_name : stream1) 
     {
   if (file_path.getFileName().toString().startsWith("values-")) 
       {
    languages = file_path.getFileName().toString().split("-"); 
   }
  }
}
```

Can you please help me simplify this code ?
I wonder if i have to 2 times use Directory stream.

Comment: I would suggest posting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the code you provide solves the problem you described. But assuming it does - there are couple of suggestions:

- `DirectoryStream` should be closed. If you are not using a
  `try-with-resources` statement, don't forget to close the stream in
  the `finally` block.
- Also, to make code readable - I would suggest to split this method in
  several simpler methods each with single responsibility.

So, here is one possible approach to make code *in a way* cleaner:

```
public List<String> getLanguages(String directoryPath) throws IOException {
  List<String> languages = new ArrayList<>();
  try (DirectoryStream<Path> paths = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(directoryPath))) {
    for (Path filePath : paths) {
      try (DirectoryStream<Path> filePaths = Files.newDirectoryStream(filePath, "strings.xml")) {
        languages.addAll(getValues(filePaths));
      }
    }
  }
  return languages;
}

private List<String> getValues(DirectoryStream<Path> paths) {
  return StreamSupport.stream(paths.spliterator(), false)
      .map(path -> path.getFileName().toString())
      .filter(fileName -> fileName.startsWith("values-"))
      .flatMap(fileName -> Arrays.stream(fileName.split("-")))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer , i did not use it in my file , but I have learn something new from that code. <pl>Dziekuje</pl> :)